# Filling with no holes SVG paths that include open subpaths inside

Tags: css, svg

Is is possible to fill without holes a path that contains an open subpath like the one in the example?
I've tried fiddling with fill-rule css property and [order of points in the subpath to alter the winding order](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch06-fill-rule.html#fill-rule-markers-figure), but at least one hole is always present.

[Codepen live-demo](https://codepen.io/40detectives/pen/GREqqNq)

```css
path {
  fill: aqua;
  stroke: red;
  /* fill-rule: evenodd; */
  fill-rule: nonzero;
}
```

```html
<svg width="600px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 2400 600">
  <path d="M0,0 L1200,0 v0,600 h-1200,0Z M200,300 Q400,50 600,300 T1000,300" stroke-width="5"/>
  <path d="M1200,0 L2400,0 v0,600 h-1200,0Z M2200,300 Q2000,550 1800,300 T1400,300" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Why not color the background of the SVG? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NWgrbpq

Comment: That could work with very simple SVG nodes, but not when your path is part of a more complex SVG structure. For example I'm composing a complex graph using D3.

Comment: Break your path in 2 paths by the M command